# why i cant build react / electron

Tags: reactjs, webpack, electron

When I'm about to package the React/Electron app after it's assembled into the dist folder, I get an error:

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HP7qG.png)

package.json:

```
 {
  "name": "webpackelectron",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "zxcx",
  "main": "src/electron/main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --open",
    "build": "webpack --mode production",
    "pack:linux": "electron-builder -c.extraMetadata.main=build/main.js --publish never",
    "pack:windows": "electron-builder --win -c.extraMetadata.main=dist/main.js --publish never",
    "start:electron": "cross-env ELECTRON_START_URL=http://localhost:3000 electron .",
    "test": "concurrently \"cross-env BROWSER=none PORT=3000 webpack-dev-server \" \"set ELECTRON_START_URL=http://localhost:3000 && electron .\""
  },
  "build": {
    "win": {
      "target": "nsis" 
    },
    "files": [
      "dist/**/*" 
    ]
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.23.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.22.20",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.22.15",
    "babel-loader": "^9.1.3",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0",
    "css-loader": "^6.8.1",
    "electron": "^26.2.4",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.3",
    "less-loader": "^11.1.3",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.3",
    "webpack": "^5.88.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.15.1",
    "electron-prebuilt-compile": "8.2.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.12.1",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.6",
    "concurrently": "^8.2.1",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "electron-cli": "^0.2.8",
    "electron-is-dev": "^2.0.0",
    "path-browserify": "^1.0.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-redux": "^8.1.3",
    "react-router": "^6.16.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.16.0",
    "styled-components": "^6.0.8"
  }
}
```

webpack:

```
 const path = require("path");
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require("clean-webpack-plugin");
const HTMLWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
module.exports = {
  mode: "development",
  entry: ["@babel/polyfill", "./src/index.jsx"],
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
    filename: "[name].[hash].js",
    publicPath: './'
  },
  devServer: {
    port: 3000,
  },
  resolve: {
    aliasFields: [],
    fallback: {
      fs: false, // отключаем добавление fs модуля
      path: require.resolve('path-browserify'), // используем path-browserify вместо path
    },
  },
  plugins: [new HTMLWebpackPlugin({ template: "./src/utils/index.html" })],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(css|less)/,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "less-loader"],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jpg|jpeg|png|svg)/,
        use: ["file-loader"],
      },
      {
        test: /\.mp3$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "file-loader",
            options: {
              name: 'assets/[name].[ext]'
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.m?js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
          options: {
            presets: ["@babel/preset-env"],
          },
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.jsx$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
          options: {
            presets: ["@babel/preset-react"],
          },
        },
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

builder-effective-config.yaml:

```
directories:
  output: dist
  buildResources: build
win:
  target: nsis
files:
  - filter:
      - dist/**/*
extraMetadata:
  main: dist/main.js
electronVersion: 26.2.4
```

(Config builder appears during and application)

I need the application to be assembled into a file, at the moment it is being installed, but I get an error (in the screenshot)

Comment: Please write the error instead of using an image. Some of us can't see images. [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: error is : 'PublicPath is not supported in this browser' This error appears when I try to open a file that has already been built  After reinstalling, I got the error Reference Error : Document is not defined